# Pandas apply function against column

Tags: pandas

Why is Pandas throwing an error when trying to apply this function to a column?

```
import pandas as pd
import math

data = [
    ['LAT', "LON"],
    [49.00, -83.04],
    [41.00, -83.04],
    [26.00, -83.04],
]
df= pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

print(df)
print((math.cos(49.00) * 69.172) /.25)


df['LAT'] = df['LAT'].astype(int)
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda t: ((math.cos(t['LAT']) * 69.172) /.25))
```

The error message occurs on the last line when trying to use df.apply. Output is:

```
    LAT    LON
0  49.0 -83.04
1  41.0 -83.04
2  26.0 -83.04
83.17034974333946

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['test'] = df['LAT'].apply(lambda t: ((math.cos(t) * 69.172) /.25))
print (df)
    LAT    LON        test
0  49.0 -83.04   83.170350
1  41.0 -83.04 -273.184930
2  26.0 -83.04  178.994813
```

But better is use vectorize [`numpy.cos`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html):

```
df['test'] = np.cos(df['LAT']) * 69.172 / .25
```

Comment: Yea that works but I don't know why lol, it's like the same thing. Thanks

Comment: `df['LAT']` doesn't need `.astype(int)`

Comment: Right, that was a debugging step. I'm guessing the reference to integer is something about the index.